# Unable to start VM-DeploymentVNetAddressAllocationFailure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

After been Running for about 3 months my vm has stop working properly. According to the Azure console the vm is "Running" but I'm unable to ssh into the VM, the server seems to be unresponsive.

I tried to Stop/Start it again and now I'm getting the following message:

error:   Networking.DeploymentVNetAddressAllocationFailure : Unable to allocate the required address spaces for the deployment in a new or predefined subnet that is contained within the specified virtual network.
info:    Error information has been recorded to azure.err
error:   vm start command failed

Since the VM was configure to use a Static IP address, I've removed the static IP  and also change the IP address to something else but without much success. According to the console with server is "Running" but I'm still unable to ssh into the machine
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This belongs on ServerFault.

Comment: can you be a little more specific? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Um, sure: You didn't ask a programming question. You asked a question related to servers and networks. Ergo... ServerFault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you are unable to SSH into the Azure Virtual Machines although it shows "Running" in the Management Portal. Suggest you to try the below mentioned steps

•   Restart the Virtual Machine from the Management Portal

•   Resize the Virtual Machine from the Portal but ensure to Back up the Data in the Temporary Drive ( D:) since the data will be lost while Resizing.

•   If the issue is still not fixed, please recreate the VM by retaining the attached Disk’s and attaching the same to the new VM

•   If the issue still persists, you might want to recover the VM by attaching the OS Disk to another VM . Please refer to the below mentioned blog

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mast/archive/2014/11/20/recovering-azure-vm-by-attaching-os-disk-to-another-azure-vm.aspx

Hope this helps !

Regards,

Sowmya